# Teamcity build log

Tags: encoding, teamcity

I use TeamCity for continious integration. Solution checkouts on deploy machine and builds. Deploy machine running under Windows Server 2008 R2 - Russian. There are russian language PowerShell installed etc. In TeamCity build log, all russian symbols are in wrong encoding.

How to change encoding in build log?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. change encoding for log4j configuration for build log in `conf/teamcity-agent-log4j.xml`

   ```
   <appender name="ROLL.BUILD" class="jetbrains.buildServer.util.TCRollingFileAppender">
     <param name="file" value="${teamcity_logs}teamcity-build.log"/>
     <param name="Encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
     ...
   </appender>
   ```
2. add file.encoding=UTF-8 parameter `launcher/conf/wrapper.conf` that uses agent on start
   you should add it like that

   ```
   wrapper.app.parameter.6=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
   ```
3. add `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` in `JAVA_OPTS`

that steps helps me but now i have a bug - if you watching tail new Russian symbols in log replaced by "?". after refreshing the page they shown correct.

Comment: Additional reading: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Configuring+Build+Agent+Startup+Properties

Answer (score 14):

For me, on Windows 7, TeamCity 9.0.3 helped adding "teamcity.runner.commandline.stdstreams.encoding=866" line into the buildAgent.properties file.
I've got the encoding value by typing "chcp" in the command prompt.

Comment: It's helpful with Russian encoding. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

For Teamcity 9 the next had helped:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
sudo update-locale LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

(do this being on your agents)

After that - restart the agent:

```
./BuildAgent/bin/agent.sh stop
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, on TeamCity 7 and TeamCity 8, helped editing file **teamcity-agent-log4j.xml**:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
```

and restarting TeamCity after that.

But encoding is correct only after refreshing the log page.