# UTF-8 Encoding into TeamCity 9 build log

Tags: encoding, continuous-integration, teamcity

I use TeamCity 9 for continious integration. Machine running under Windows Server 2008 R2 - Russian. There are russian language PowerShell installed etc. In TeamCity build log, all russian symbols are in wrong encoding.

How to change encoding in build log?

UPD: Also I use Intellij IDEA for creating Maven project and I have 2 sql files with UTF-8 chars.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Teamcity build log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213241/teamcity-build-log)

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following post regarding encoding in TeamCity buildlog :::
[Teamcity build log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213241/teamcity-build-log)

This sounds like the very same q...

Kind regards

Comment: This should be reported via a flag, not in an answer.